# EF6 automatically includes nested objects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Probably a simple question, but there is something I can't get my head around.

My structure Bundle -> BundleMembers -> InsuranceTypes

When I retrieve a single record form BundleMembers, and I include Bundle. EF6 automatically includes all BundleMembers in the Bundle

Example:

[image]

```
public async Task<List<BundleMember>> GetBundleMembers(string userId, bool includeBundle, bool includeInsuranceTypes)
{
    var bundleMembers = db.BundleMembers.Where(m => string.Equals(m.UserId, userId, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
    if (includeBundle)
    {
        bundleMembers = bundleMembers.Include(o => o.Bundle);
    }
    if (includeInsuranceTypes)
    {
        bundleMembers = bundleMembers.Include(m => m.BundleMemberInsuranceType);
    }

    return await bundleMembers.ToListAsync();
}
```

I call the function like this:

```
GetBundleMembers(_userManager.GetUserId(User), true, false)
```

Do I have to access the data from Bundle, to avoid this?

**EDIT 1:**
My data model looks like this:

```
public class Bundle
    {
        public int BundleId { get; set; }

        public State State { get; set; }
        public ICollection<BundleMember> Members { get; set; }
        public ICollection<InviteLink> InviteLinks { get; set; }
        public string BundleName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }

    }
    public enum State
    {
        NotApproved,
        Approved,
        Disabled,
        Rejected
    }

    public class BundleMember
    {
        public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public int BundleMemberId { get; set; }
        public int BundleId { get; set; }
        public Bundle Bundle { get; set; }
        public bool Admin { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public int Coverage { get; set; }
        public ICollection<BundleMemberInsuranceType> BundleMemberInsuranceType { get; set; }
    }
```

I did not include `BundleMemberInsuranceType` and `InviteLink` as they are working fine.

Relevant part of ApplicationDbContext:

```
public DbSet<Bundle> Bundles { get; set; }
public DbSet<BundleMember> BundleMembers { get; set; }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the additional data isn't being lazy loaded?  If you've got your properties marked virtual chances are it's loading the data when you ask for it. (Which is what the debugger will be doing)

Comment: As i am not 100% sure when lazy loading is being triggered, so i can't say that i am sure that is not the issue. 
The Members attribute is public non virtual, so that is not the issue.
I can see from the output window in visual studio that the data is being retrieved without the debugger as well.

Comment: Can you post your Entity classes, and also the relevant part of you Context class?

Comment: @jpgrassi Of course, see EDIT 1

Comment: @Frey: Lazy loading is triggered when you read/access the property. In your case it's likely the debugger is accessing it. Check the SQL Statements called, to be sure if its lazily loaded and when

Comment: @Tseng Yeah i am aware that is what lazy loading does, i was not ware what triggered it. I compared the SQL statement output, and they are the same with and without the debugger. https://www.diffnow.com/?report=5r6yp . The debugger has a higher execution time due to the break point. (Left = without debugger and Right = with debugger)

Comment: there is NO additional data in the context. since includeBundles is set to true, you have both Bundles and BundleMembers in your context (.Include() does NOTHING more, than to also load the related entries into the context). Then relationship fixup sets the navigation properties of all entries according to FK's. to have your bundles not have BundleMembers, use a new context (load members into memory, and then in another context the bundles without include) or first detach all members and set your navigation properties yourself.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro That makes perfect sense! I did try the solution you are referring to, but found the include cleaner. 
Thanks for the reply! I will implement it as suggested.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro If you post your comment as a answer, i will mark it as a solution! It works like a charm and explains my issue well!

Comment: alright, I will try to add some information in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in comments:

The described behavior is actually expected. Since `includeBundle` is set to true, both `Bundles` and referenced `BundleMembers` are in the context, and relationship fixup will set all navigation properties according to the FK relationships.

Obviously, this works both from `BundleMembers` to `Bundles` and from `Bundles` to `BundleMembers` since `.Include` does nothing more than create the SQL statements to load the related entries into the context as well and relationship fixup will do the rest.

To have the `Bundles` not have `BundleMembers`, you'll have to load them without the `BundleMembers` in the context and set the navigation properties yourself (EF will always set both direct and inverse navigation properties). In order to do this, there are two main ways:

- Either load your bundles in a fresh context without the previous loaded `BundleMembers` (best practice is to load them into memory since EF navigation properties are loaded due to eager loading; you could have entries attached to two contexts and an exception will be thrown) or
- Detach your `BundleMembers` from the context before loading the `Bundles` into it.